# Typescript: How to iterate over an object with unknown string keys

Tags: typescript

I am trying to consume an API using javascript.

An endpoint can give me an object with unique keys each time, for example:

```
{
  "-MKlw6VSTSf-FPBaTxfB": {
    "created_at": 1603934385.9833121,
    "jugadores": 0,
    "posiciones": 4
  },
  "-MKlxam1Zjtz14wZgMNp": {
    "created_at": 1603934776.2540152,
    "jugadores": 0,
    "posiciones": 4
  },
  "-MKm8JvbKJmMAumJbmoU": {
    "created_at": 1603937848.809657,
    "jugadores": 0,
    "posiciones": 4
  },
  "-ML3-HtshKPcKrME5Jk6": {
    "created_at": 1604237470.857504,
    "jugadores": 0,
    "posiciones": 4
  }
}
```

Or it can give me an error like this one:

```
{
  "error": true,
  "mensaje": "Hubo un error"
}
```

I have declared this types:

```
type APIError = {
  error: boolean
  mensaje: string
}

type ListadoJuegosPublicos = {
  [key:string]: {
    jugadores: number
    posiciones: number
    created_at: number
  }
}
```

And I have this function signature to retrieve the data:

```
async juegosPublicos ():Promise<APIError|ListadoJuegosPublicos>
```

The function works as expected. But when I try to iterate over the response, I get this error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'APIError | ListadoJuegosPublicos'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'APIError | ListadoJuegosPublicos'.ts(7053)
```

This is the code I am trying to use to iterate over objects

```
const juegos = await api.juegosPublicos()
if (juegos.error && typeof juegos.mensaje === 'string') {
  console.error(mensaje)
  return
}

Object.keys(juegos).forEach((juegoId:string) => {
  console.log(juegos[juegoId]) // <- this is the line than generates the error
})
```

How can I correctly iterate over this object in typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start: I don't see why you're checking `juegos.error` for truthiness.  If `juegos` is an `APIError` then this value is either `true` or `false`; if it is `false` then you shouldn't be checking for truthiness since you'd erroneously conclude that it is not an `APIError`, which it is.  If `juegos` is a `ListadoJuegosPublicos` then this value is either `undefined` or an object; if it is an object, then you shouldn't be checking for truthiness since you'd erroneously conclude that it is an `APIError`, which it is not.

In what follows, I will only preserve the `typeof juegos.mensaje === 'string'` check, since this should be sufficient to determine if something is or is not an `APIError`.

---

Apparently, even though *you* understand that `typeof juegos.mensaje !== 'string'` implies that `juegos` is a `ListadoJuegosPublicos`, the compiler does *not* understand this, and does not perform [control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010)-based narrowing on `juegos`.  That is, the check on `juegos.mensaje` does not act as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) on `juegos`.

It looks like maybe `ListadoJuegosPublicos` having an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) is the issue, and if so, perhaps [microsoft/TypeScript#17960](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17960) is the relevant open GitHub issue, listed as a bug.  If so, it looks like it's not going to be addressed anytime soon.

In any case, when the compiler does not recognize some code as a type guard, you have the option of extracting that code out to your own [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).  For example:

```
function isAPIError(x: APIError | ListadoJuegosPublicos): x is APIError {
  return (typeof x.mensaje === 'string');
}
```

This is the same check as before, but explicitly marked as a type guard function that takes a value named `x` and returns a `boolean` value that determines whether or not the compiler treats `x` as an `APIError`.  Now we call the type guard function in your original code:

```
  if (isAPIError(juegos)) {
    console.error(juegos.mensaje)
    return
  }

  Object.keys(juegos).forEach((juegoId: string) => {
    console.log(juegos[juegoId]) // okay now
  });
```

and it works.  After the `return` statement, the compiler now recognizes that `juegos` must be a `ListadoJuegosPublicos` and allows the string index iteration.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAggCgSQKICcUHsVQLxQN4BQUUEamAXFAEbroA2EAhgHZFQC2EzAzowFYRK3YCgCWzAOYEAvgQKhIUADKjhjACboAUgFcIE9Nzg6qdUQGNDOfGwDaAawgghI8RIC6lPFDbE+OiQ1MCG5KZh12KlJfKDBDC1F0ZhCwiKiUNllZAgAzHWZzYETmKFV4ZDIUAAoAD0py1AwsAB9lVWAg3X1DY1MLQwBKShrS7lhERswbYhQIYB0UEqqFCHQcqBqAOk4efmhsA6gAcmExSSOBgG4ZOTyCoqSoHNoq-27Q8YqmqFaVNU0ugYjCYzJZuANpqV1lUyhNKq89ECBhDCMRiJYePQIJtSE0Ee9tlxeAIBjFZvNFpk5MQAPJUASFTaOEDcfFIzbPFBIRjmAAWVTZ6AQ6hcZwkEOwAD5IeiktwsZs6OgJILuLY3gZhe4IQB6HVQdD2RggKDMdAAd0yVzksiAA)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Actual issue is with below line

```
async juegosPublicos ():Promise<APIError|ListadoJuegosPublicos>
```

One thing you can do is replace type with any:

```
async juegosPublicos ():Promise<any>
```